# Python dictionary unavailable list

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am doing a Python regex to extract some data from a log file. A minimalistic output of the regex stored in a dictionary is shown below to highlight the issue:

```
data = {'kIters': [['6', '5']], 'kMin': [['-0.00162439495203']]}
time = ['1', '2']
```

and I am trying to do the following

```
for n,v in data.items():
    for i in xrange(len(v)):
        print ("%s_%d" %(n, i))
        for j in xrange(len(time)):
            print ("%s"%v[i][j])
```

The last line fails since the the `kMin` has only one value in its list. Is there a way to tackle when the length of `kMin` would differ from that of either `kIters` or `time`? or Is there a way to add `0` to `kMin` as the first item in the list and make it as `[['0', '-0.00162439495203']]`, which will then easily solve the issue.

Note that the Python regex will not be able to get two values for `kMin` because of the fact that there is only one instance of `kMin` present in the log file while, there are two instances of `kIters` and `time`.

Comment: what are you using `time` for? (plus a side note - you're shadowing a common library while doing so)

Comment: `time` is needed  because the value of `kIters [6, 5]` is for `time [1, 2]` while the single value of `kMin` is for time `[2]` Thanks @ReutSharabani

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do... This is confuse.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your use case is, but instead of `len(time)` you could do `len(v[i])`.  That will print out all of the items in the lists.